# How to achieve subnav in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. I can get main nav bar through  tag. How can i get subnav in bootstrap3. Please anyone help me to get the subnav in bootstrap.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with subnav?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this you will get subnav 

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
```